# Batch extract rars with spaces in names

Tags: file, batch-file, space

I am trying to batch extract some rar's that are in some zip in some directories. Long story short this is my loop through the rar files:

```
for %%r in (*.rar) do (

unrar x %%r
)
```

Problem is that %%r gets the wrong value. If the files name is "file name.rar" then %%r gets the value "file" - it stops at the first space in the file name.

How do I get this loop to work file files with spaces in names?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "usebackq delims==" %i in (`dir /b *.rar`) do unrar x "%i"
```

If you are using it in a batch file, remember you will need to double the percent signs to escape them.

Answer (score 1):

`%%r` will contain the complete file name including spaces. It's your call to `unrar` which has the problem. If the file name contains spaces you have to enclose it in quotation marks, otherwise `unrar` won't be able to see that the two (space-separated) parameters `file` and `name.rar` are actually a single filename with a space.

So the following will work:

```
for %%r in (*.rar) do unrar "%%r"
```

Also, if you aer curious where the problem lies, it's sometimes very helpful to simply replace the program call with echo:

```
for %%r in (*.rar) do @echo %%r
```

where you will see that %%r includes the spaces in file names and doesn't rip them apart.

Comment: I thought of that, but it still wouldn't work like that. It seams that %%r really had a wrong value and quotes would do much.

Maybe I got something else wrong... I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 'for' uses space as the default delimited. You can set this using the delims = xxx. look [here](http://www.ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) for syntax. Or you can use [ForFiles](http://www.ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html).

Comment: cmd is also not a UNIX shell which does globbing wherever it sees an asterisk. For every rar file you will have its filename completely contained in %%r, regardless of it having spaces or not.